# Running lights off of a 50amp spa

Tags: electrical

I have a 2-pole 50amp breaker in my panel supplying my sauna external controller with 4 wire(control unit doesn't use the neutral so just capped of inside it). I want to add a couple led lights inside. Is there a way to run a 15amp branch circuit from the sauna control unit to achieve this? I would rather not run a separate line as it would not be ideal.

Comment: Is there a sub-panel at the spa end of the cable/conduit?

Comment: What spa controller? Some of them have aux power outputs.